# Problems installing software on AWS EC2 instance (Debian 7.8 'hvm')

Tags: amazon-ec2, installation, grub, grub2

After some issues due to the lack of support in required kernel for the network card in my machine (though I'm aware of how to compile the driver for my card, I don't want to do that, based on some issues with kernel headers for the target kernel), I have decided to try an alternate route - install the software I'm evaluating on AWS EC2 (I have some limited prior experience working with EC2).

The software I'm evaluating (HUBzero - an open source platform for scientific research and collaboration) is a large and complex suite of various software modules. That is OK, however, for full functionality, it requires (and tries to install) using non-default (for Debian 7) kernel, specifically, a 2.6-based OpenVZ kernel. While most of the installation beyond the OpenVZ kernel was successful and required just a bit of configuring and tweaking (since installation instructions are for standard Debian 7 installation, not on AWS - there exists - in AWS Marketplace - a HUBzero VM image, but of significantly older version, hence my efforts to install/evaluate the most recent one).

Anyway, when I tried to install the HUBzero's package with OpenVZ kernel image, it produced the following output with some warnings (see "Hmm" messages below) and, finally, an error. If I understand correctly, the error is due to lack of installed 'grub' on my pilot system. Note that I'm using ['hvm' virtualization instead of 'pvm'](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/virtualization_types.html), so [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/UserProvidedKernels.html) is not applicable. Thus, I decided to install GRUB via 'apt-get' and then removed it, expecting to find the legacy (v1) version, which uses "/boot/grub/grub.cfg", expected by the installation script. However, despite the message "Note, selecting 'grub-legacy' instead of 'grub'", I don't see 'grub' configuration file as well as related the '.lst' file.

**Question:** how to setup GRUB, as expected by HUBzero's installation script (which seems to rely on GRUB v1), and fix the situation, in general? All advice and/or help will be much appreciated.

Happy holidays!

**Promised Output:**

```
Output from "apt-get install hubzero-openvz":
---------------------------------------------

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libcgroup1 libparted0debian1 libploop1 linux-image-2.6.32-openvz-042stab112.15-amd64 linux-image-openvz-amd64 parted ploop vzctl
  vzquota
Suggested packages:
  libparted0-dev libparted0-i18n fdutils linux-doc-2.6.32-openvz-042stab112.15-amd64 linux-source-2.6.32-openvz-042stab112.15-amd64
  ksymoops linux-image-2.6.32-openvz-042stab112.15-amd64-dbg parted-doc pv bash-completion
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  hubzero-openvz libcgroup1 libparted0debian1 libploop1 linux-image-2.6.32-openvz-042stab112.15-amd64 linux-image-openvz-amd64
  parted ploop vzctl vzquota
0 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 30 not upgraded.
Need to get 56.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 161 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
Get:1 http://cloudfront.debian.net/debian/ wheezy/main libparted0debian1 amd64 2.3-12 [348 kB]
Get:2 http://download.openvz.org/debian/ wheezy/main linux-image-2.6.32-openvz-042stab112.15-amd64 amd64 1 [55.0 MB]
Get:3 http://packages.hubzero.org/deb/ ellie-deb7/main hubzero-openvz amd64 2.0.0-1+deb7 [2,300 B]
Get:4 http://cloudfront.debian.net/debian/ wheezy/main libcgroup1 amd64 0.38-1 [43.8 kB]
Get:5 http://cloudfront.debian.net/debian/ wheezy/main parted amd64 2.3-12 [158 kB]
Get:6 http://download.openvz.org/debian/ wheezy/main vzquota amd64 3.1-1 [105 kB]
Get:7 http://download.openvz.org/debian/ wheezy/main vzctl amd64 4.9.4-2 [351 kB]
Get:8 http://download.openvz.org/debian/ wheezy/main libploop1 amd64 1.13.2-1 [102 kB]
Get:9 http://download.openvz.org/debian/ wheezy/main linux-image-openvz-amd64 amd64 042stab112.15 [3,118 B]
Get:10 http://download.openvz.org/debian/ wheezy/main ploop amd64 1.13.2-1 [38.5 kB]
Fetched 56.1 MB in 8s (6,948 kB/s)
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package libparted0debian1:amd64.
(Reading database ... 116346 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libparted0debian1:amd64 (from .../libparted0debian1_2.3-12_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-2.6.32-openvz-042stab112.15-amd64.
Unpacking linux-image-2.6.32-openvz-042stab112.15-amd64 (from .../linux-image-2.6.32-openvz-042stab112.15-amd64_1_amd64.deb) ...
Done.
Selecting previously unselected package libcgroup1.
Unpacking libcgroup1 (from .../libcgroup1_0.38-1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package vzquota.
Unpacking vzquota (from .../vzquota_3.1-1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package vzctl.
Unpacking vzctl (from .../vzctl_4.9.4-2_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package parted.
Unpacking parted (from .../parted_2.3-12_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libploop1:amd64.
Unpacking libploop1:amd64 (from .../libploop1_1.13.2-1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-openvz-amd64.
Unpacking linux-image-openvz-amd64 (from .../linux-image-openvz-amd64_042stab112.15_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package hubzero-openvz.
Unpacking hubzero-openvz (from .../hubzero-openvz_2.0.0-1+deb7_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ploop.
Unpacking ploop (from .../ploop_1.13.2-1_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up libparted0debian1:amd64 (2.3-12) ...
Setting up linux-image-2.6.32-openvz-042stab112.15-amd64 (1) ...

 Hmm. There is a symbolic link /lib/modules/2.6.32-openvz-042stab112.15-amd64/build
 However, I can not read it: No such file or directory
 Therefore, I am deleting /lib/modules/2.6.32-openvz-042stab112.15-amd64/build


 Hmm. The package shipped with a symbolic link /lib/modules/2.6.32-openvz-042stab112.15-amd64/source
 However, I can not read the target: No such file or directory
 Therefore, I am deleting /lib/modules/2.6.32-openvz-042stab112.15-amd64/source

Running depmod.
WARNING: could not open /lib/modules/2.6.32-openvz-042stab112.15-amd64/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 2.6.32-openvz-042stab112.15-amd64 /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-openvz-042stab112.15-amd64
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-openvz-042stab112.15-amd64
WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_iDGwaW/lib/modules/2.6.32-openvz-042stab112.15-amd64/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-extlinux 2.6.32-openvz-042stab112.15-amd64 /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-openvz-042stab112.15-amd64
P: Checking for EXTLINUX directory... found.
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-openvz-042stab112.15-amd64...
P: Updating /boot/extlinux/linux.cfg...
Setting up libcgroup1 (0.38-1) ...
Setting up vzquota (3.1-1) ...
Setting up vzctl (4.9.4-2) ...
Running kernel is not an OpenVZ kernel
invoke-rc.d: initscript vz, action "start" failed.
Setting up parted (2.3-12) ...
Setting up libploop1:amd64 (1.13.2-1) ...
Setting up linux-image-openvz-amd64 (042stab112.15) ...
Setting up hubzero-openvz (2.0.0-1+deb7) ...
Setting up ploop (1.13.2-1) ...

=====

Output from "hzcms configure openvz --enable":
----------------------------------------------

enabling openvz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/hzcms", line 5159, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/bin/hzcms", line 3703, in _openvzConfigure
    openvzEnable()
  File "/usr/bin/hzcms", line 3744, in openvzEnable
    grubfh = open(grubfn,'r')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/boot/grub/grub.cfg'
```